# Trouble aligning rows in two columns using makecell

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, makecell

Been trying to align columns two and three (vertically) but can't figure it out. Columns are coming up central to "Workability" instead, and as column two has some rows taking up 2 lines, they don't match up. Here's what I've got..

```
\usepackage{makecell}
\newcommand{\aspect}{%
\makecell[l]{Practicality\\Controlling factors\\Knocking-up\\Type of lime\\Impacts}%
}
\newcommand{\key}{%
\makecell*[l{p{85mm}}]{Mortar needs to be easy to work so the mason won't add more water\\Water retentivity, water content, internal friction, surface area, air content, density, consistency\\Consistency reintroduced without need for extra water\\Hydrated lime more workable than hydraulic\\Strength (particularly bond strength), water resistance and workmanship}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.5}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{p{15mm}p{30mm}p{85mm}} \toprule
   & Aspect   & Key Characteristics \\ \midrule
Workability & \aspect & \key \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I initially had the following...but as you can see, "Workability" wasn't actually central.

```
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin {table} [ht]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\centering
\begin{tabular} {l l p{8.5cm}}     %3 left aligned columns
\hline
& Aspect & Key Characteristic(s) \\
\hline
\multirow{5}{*}{Workability} 
& Practicality & Mortar needs to be easy to work so the mason won't add more water \\
& Controlling factors & Water retentivity, water content, internal friction, surface area, air content, density, consistency \\
& "Knocking-up" & Consistency reintroduced without need for extra water \\ 
& Type of lime & Hydrated lime more workable than hydraulic \\
& Impacts & Strength (particularly bond strength), water resistance and workmanship \\    
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Workability}
\label{table:Workability}    %table reference in text
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For vertically centred alignment of the first column, and by-row alignment of columns two and three, it's much easier to control things by setting them within a `tabular` manually:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{makecell,booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{lp{30mm}p{85mm}}
    \toprule
    & Aspect   & Key Characteristics \\
    \midrule
    & Practicality & Mortar needs to be easy to work so the mason won't add more water \\
    & Controlling factors & Water retentivity, water content, internal friction, surface area, air content, density, consistency \\
    \smash{\raisebox{\normalbaselineskip}{Workability}} & Knocking-up & Consistency reintroduced without need for extra water \\
    & Type of lime & Hydrated lime more workable than hydraulic \\
    & Impacts & Strength (particularly bond strength), water resistance and workmanship
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

`\smash`ing the entry in the first columns allows one to raise it by one line (or `\normalbaselineskip`) to be vertically centred with the column 2. Technically, you may only want to raise it `.5\normalbaselineskip` for it to be in the middle.

Another option (although not needed) would be to use `\multirow` (from the [`multirow` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/multirow)).

Comment: Ideally, I would like "Workability" central (vertically), which I had no problem with. But would like each of the 5 inputs in column 2 to line up with the 5 inputs in column 3.

Comment: .5\normalbaselineskip works well, sticking with that